# JComboxBox setSelectedItem

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am facing problem to set a perticulat value of a custom JComboBox. If I call `setSelectedItem()` from the `initialize()` method of the following class it is not selecting the particular value.

The extended JComboBox class is:

```
public class ThemeComboBox extends JComboBox {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 50L;

    public ThemeComboBox(DefaultComboBoxModel model) {
        super(model);
        initialize();
        LibraryLogger.initMessage(getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    public void initialize() {
        ThemeComboBoxModel model = (ThemeComboBoxModel) getModel();
        for(ThemeModel themeModel : model.getThemeModels()) {
            if(themeModel.getThemeClass().equals(ConfigurationManager.getInstance().getUiManager().getUiProperties().getTheme())) {
                setSelectedItem(themeModel);
                System.out.println("=========");
                break;
            }
        }
        addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                ThemeComboBox themeComboBox = (ThemeComboBox) actionEvent.getSource();
                System.out.println(themeComboBox.getSelectedItem());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

While if I override the `getSelectedItem()` of custom DefaultComboBoxModel then it is selecting that value but on choosing other value the selection remain same or it remain unchange.
The model class is:

```
public class ThemeComboBoxModel extends DefaultComboBoxModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 51L;

    private Vector<ThemeModel> themeModels;

    public ThemeComboBoxModel(Vector<ThemeModel> models) {
        super(models);
    }

    public Vector<ThemeModel> getThemeModels() {
        return themeModels;
    }

    public void setThemeModels(Vector<ThemeModel> themeModels) {
        this.themeModels = themeModels;
    }

    /*@Override
    public Object getSelectedItem() {
        for(ThemeModel themeModel : themeModels) {
            if(themeModel.getThemeClass().equals(ConfigurationManager.getInstance().getUiManager().getUiProperties().getTheme())) {
                return themeModel;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }*/
}
```

I am unable to understand what I am doing wrong. Any information will be very helpful to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I hope that main method is initialized from `invokeLater`

2) Swing is single threaded, where output to the GUI is done quite in one moment

3) there isn't any guarantee that all events have got any order, basically isn't possible ordering events for Swing GUI, same/especially on GUI startup

4) show GUI (`setVisible(true);`), then last codeline will be `JComboBox#setSelectedItem(int or Object)`, wrapped inside `invokeLater`

5) add `Listeners` only if needed, remove useless `Listeners`